# Compiling Eclipse Project With 1.7 Compilance Settings

Tags: eclipse

Right Click On project -> Properties -> Java Compiler

I select 1.7 to Use Default Compliance Settings. I click OK and it compiles the project.

I notice I tiny/little red 'x' next to my project. The code still compiles but I know it won't work after deployment.

I drag my jstl-1.2 JRE file into the WEB-INF folder -- nothing. I drag it everywhere else and still nothing.

Last hope I have is to Java Build Path -> Libraries tab -> Add  External JAR and choose the same jstl-1.2 JRE file. Still nothing.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Check what version of JRE library are you using for the project. Right click on project -> Build Path config -> Libraries

Comment: where is the download like for the lastest JDK? and wat would I do w/it

Comment: If you do not have JDK 7 and you set your project compliance to that version, the project will have that 'x' mark you said. Download JDK 7 from here - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html based on the OS version you have and then install it. Set the environment variables and have eclipse use the JRE v7 library for your project in the Build Path config.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I have windows 7 and JDK 7 already installed. I navigate to where Java is installed, but what do I choose?

Comment: In the project build path configuration, there's a Libraries tab. What is the version of JRE system library there?

Comment: It says JRE System Library [jre1.8.0_40]

Comment: Yeah, so go to Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JRE's and check the version 7 JRE there. Go to the build path config again and verify it says JRE System Lib v7 now. Refresh the project. That ought to fix it.

Comment: It shows me: Execution Environments under that JavaSE-1.8. So I click that and it shows me Compatible JRE's: jre1.8.0_40

Comment: Ok, not sure what's the problem then.

Comment: OK so go to Project Facets and it should become obvious. Just so anyone else has a question, that is perhaps a solution.